# How do I write this key from a table

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, key

I need to know how to write a foreign key in table description.

I have 3 tables A, B, C

There is only simple relationship (1,1 <-> 0,n)
Primary key in bold, foreign key with #.

[image]

C is : C(**CKey**)

B is : B(**Bkey**,#Ckey)

A is : A(**Akey**, #ForeignKey)

How to write the #ForeignKey present in A ? It is made with the primary key of B, but how to write it ? 
is (#BKey,##Ckey) right ?

Comment: What text or method or language are you using?

Comment: I don't use any langage, and i am not sure about what you mean when you say about method.

My question is inspired from an test. The test give a entity-relationship diagram and we have to find the tables as this : MyTable(**primaryKey**, #ForeignKey, Data1, Data2,...).

The corection is : A(**Akey**,#BKey,#Ckey), but i think this is wrong.

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. It seems like wrong terms adn notation and fragments of information. What are # and ##? Dont understand "There is only simple relation (1,1 <-> 0,n)". A "relation" is a table. Maybe you mean "relationship". I don't understand "There is only simple relationship (1,1 <-> 0,n)" either. Between what and what? And now I hear you had a diagram; do you expect us to answer without the diagram? Take time and be very clear.

Comment: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/23/1402242475-nouvelle-image-bitmap-2.png
is that more clear ? I wonder how to write the 3 tables made from this 3 entities (especially the table A).
And the reason why i ask this is because the correction says : A(**Akey**,#Bkey,#Ckey), but for me this is wrong.

Comment: Edit your question until it contains the information in the picture. And everything else I asked for. The picture gives some cardinalilty information but it disagrees with a bigger description already in you question. So I doubt the picture is right.